# Spock Parametrized Specification doesn't work with CompileStatic

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

prerequisites:
Adopt OpenJDK 11,
Gradle 6.8.1,
Groovy 3.0,
Spock 2.0,

Firstly I've got exceptions dependence with inner static builder class:

```
 #: [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method java.lang.Object#withSomeMethod(int). Please check if the declared type is correct and if the method exists.
```

@ line #, column #.
.withSomeMethod(1)

Then I declared variables in Class Specification. But I've got exceptions:

```
SomeSpec.groovy: 12: where-blocks may only contain parameterizations
```

How can I integrate static compile with Spock Parameterization Tests?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the community

> @CompileStatic is not really supported for Spock, it works for some cases but not in others. In general I recommend not to use it for specs.
> https://gitter.im/spockframework/spock?at=61aa07658f98cb0811a2cdb1